# Java always trim a zero fractional part in an Object class?

Tags: java, object, casting, formatting, numbers

I have Map<String, Object> where Object is List and one them - Double. **Debugger show [0.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNd7E.png) **,
but **result in Swagger [0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCw5O.png)**. Can I save fractional part like a number (not String) with the same structure?

I tried DecimalFormat and so on, but they gave string format response, I need numeric format.

Comment: Would you identify the library used for transferring a Java object to JSON string?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.